# Mobile only soft-hyphen using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to use a soft hyphen `&shy;` to optionally break a word.
It should only be applied on mobile, not on desktop (ideally through HTML + CSS alone).

**Reason:** The word fits fine on desktop but due to the rest of the sentence it still gets broken up.

Answer (score 0):

You can can wrap the soft-hyphen in a `<span>` and apply **media-queries**.
This way you could even have different soft-hyphens depending on the device-type.

**Example:**

```css
.container{
    max-width: 200px;
    background: #cfcfcf;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .mobile-only{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitäten<span class="mobile-only">&shy;</span>hauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft
</div>
```